# Dagger2 - Injection in an Android app with Instant App and Dynamic Modules support

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm trying to setup a boilerplate/proof of concept repository of an Android application that has Instant App and Dynamic Module support, while injecting some third party libraries like Room and Retrofit. It is written in Kotlin. The code can be found at [GitHub - Stabber](https://github.com/simpers/Stabber).

I am on the step of adding support for the SplitCompat API so that I can dynamically install Dynamic Modules, as described in [App Bundle - Play Core Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore#invoke_splitcompat_at_runtime).

In this guide it is described that one can use `SplitCompatApplication` as their application implementation in their android manifest (and here I am assuming this part goes in the base module's manifest, due to the dependency model of all modules, correct me if I'm wrong).

What I did was follow the section where it is describing what `SplitCompatApplication` is actually doing, and it is said that it just overrides `Application`'s as stated here:

> `SplitCompatApplication` simply overrides `ContextWrapper.attachBaseContext()` to include `SplitCompat.install(Context applicationContext)`. If you don’t want your `Application` class to extend `SplitCompatApplication`, you can override the `attachBaseContext()` method manually, as follows:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    // Emulates installation of future on demand modules using SplitCompat.
    SplitCompat.install(this);
}
```

So I did do exactly this, but with the version that takes into account that I am supporting Instant Apps, so my body of this function override is actually:

```
override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base)
    val isInstant = InstantApps.isInstantApp(this)
    if (!isInstant) {
        SplitCompat.install(this)
    }
}
```

So apart from the code shown in the previously linked guide, I am just taking out the check and storing it in a variable, which still yields the same result. My problem is that I cannot run my application anymore, as it throws this exception:

```
Process: app.instant.stabber.app, PID: 6788
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application app.instant.stabber.android.StabberApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application context is null!
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1017)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5940)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1755)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application context is null!
        at com.google.android.instantapps.InstantApps.isInstantApp(InstantApps.java:62)
        at app.instant.stabber.android.StabberApplication.attachBaseContext(StabberApplication.kt:30)
        at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:218)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1091)
```

I have even tried something like this in order to fix the fact that the Context (the application..?) seems to be Null:

```
 override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base)
    this?.let { me ->
        val isInstant = InstantApps.isInstantApp(me)
        if (!isInstant) {
            SplitCompat.install(me)
        }
    }
}
```

I really can't figure out where to go from here though. Does anybody have any ideas of what is causing this? The only thing I can think of is that something's wrong with the manifests, because that's what I've struggled with a lot before. The manifests and the fact that the way resources are handled in this modularisation of Android apps is very odd (some string values I've had to put in base instead of instant features, etc).

EDIT: In the current code I am not overriding it manually to accomodate Instant Apps (as suggested by the guide I have linked) and instead I just subclass SplitCompatApplication. It seems to run but I have not yet tested installing any dynamic modules.

EDIT 2: What I came up with in the end, but I want to know why I have to do this in the frist place even though I followed the exact instructions:

```
override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base)
    this.applicationContext?.let { _ ->
        val isInstant = InstantApps.isInstantApp(this)
        if (!isInstant) {
            SplitCompat.install(this)
        }
    }
}
```